# DHCP Server stops handing out leases

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, connection, internet

I currently have a DC running Windows Sever 2008 R2 (yes I know) and for the past two weeks, when employees travel back to the office, they can't connect to the internet unless I do one of two things.

1. Reboot the DC
2. Give them a static IP

The DC also hosts the DHCP and DNS roles. So I've checked and checked for errors but can't find anything and nothing has changed on that DC in that time. Does anyone have any thoughts or recommendations to what I can do? Thank you.

Happy Halloween!

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the question.  Do the affected clients still hold a lease when they get into this state ?  I'm assuming they are Windows clients - what's the output of "ipconfig /all" ?  Have the clients been able to renew a lease ?

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the response. 

So since I've posted this I've done some testing with both machines that haven't been on the network before and others that have. It's odd because a brand new Mac Mini connected without fail out of the box while other laptops already on the domain did fail. 

I did check IP for failing machines and even IP release/renew never had them get a DHCP lease. 

I just recently took a look into Task Manager and Resource Manager on our DC and can see that the memory was maxed out. I uninstalled print server role and rebooted and all is okay...for now.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @HeyHelpDeskGuy.  As a complete aside (and for what it's worth), I'm actually on a MacMini (have been for years).  They actually make really good workstations - regardless of whether you're on Windows or macOS.  Thanks again, Patrick